# Asp label replace by HTML label I want text property for HTML label

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using html label in Asp.net website.
I want HTML label Text property

How to declare text property for HTML label control ?

Comment: please describe more what exactly do you want ?

Comment: what do you mean by label Text property?

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblHeaderName" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResources, lbl_FinalInspection %>"></asp:Label>  Replace HTML label like  <label for="male" Text="Male"></label>  but this is not working

Comment: so do you want to add text inside label ?

Comment: Yes sir i want HTML label property

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: Make that HTML label as server control by adding `runat="server"` then you will able to get text property of that label

Comment: Do you want to have a default text in the label or do you want to add text in the application runtime by .text = "texthere" ?? The actual declaration of the label is done in ASPX if you are using Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your text inside `<label>` tag:

```
<label runat="server" id="lblHello">Hello</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your label looks like this,

```
<label runat="server" id="label1"></label>
```

If you'd like to set a text to the label, what you can do is to assign the value to `InnerText` property.

```
label1.InnerText = "TEST";
```

Also, you can use `InnerHtml` property for adding HTML value.

```
label1.InnerHTML = "<h1>TEST</h1>"
```

Answer (score 0):

<%= HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Your resource name", "your resource key") %> < label>